# Best way to input Products into CRM

Tags: tree, dynamics-crm, implementation, product

I would like to know what the best way to input products into CRM? I don’t much like how it is laid out in CRM now. I would like it to look more like a tree. Such as listed below.

Manufacturer: Akzo

Brand: Sikkens

Primer Brand: U-Tech

Primer Part Numbers: 399199 2K100 Grey

```
                             399200 2K Buff
```

Sealer Brand: 398745 ColorBuild Plus

Basecoat Color System: AutoBase Plus

Basecoat Reducer: 394695 Lesonal Reducer

Clearcoat Brand (1): Sikkens

Clearcoat Brand (1) Part Numbers: 381164 Autoclear III

Clearcoat Brand (2): U-Tech

Clearcoat Brand (2) Part Numbers: 399099 4.0 Clear

Please help. I appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0):

CRM has a data import wizard under tools.  You can use that to import data from a csv file.

Comment: Is there anyway to make the products look more like a subject tree then just a huge list?

Comment: Not out of the box.  If you wanted that hierarchical view you could write your own aspx page that queried the product and displayed it like the subject trees.